# ClassNotFoundException with Wiremock 2.5.1 and Spring Boot 1.5.1

Tags: spring-boot, wiremock

I'm having problems when trying to configure a test infrastructure in Spring Boot 1.5.1.RELEASE and Wiremock 2.5.1. It's throwing:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/HttpClient
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockApp.buildStubRequestHandler(WireMockApp.java:124)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer.<init>(WireMockServer.java:71)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit.WireMockRule.<init>(WireMockRule.java:42)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit.WireMockRule.<init>(WireMockRule.java:38)
    at br.com.mobicare.minhaoi.WiremockTest.<clinit>(WiremockTest.java:21)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:142)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:1088)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:1069)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkField.get(FrameworkField.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.getAnnotatedFieldValues(TestClass.java:230)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.classRules(ParentRunner.java:255)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.withClassRules(ParentRunner.java:244)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.classBlock(ParentRunner.java:194)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:362)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:253)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 28 more
```

I`ve used Wiremock 2.4.1 and Spring Boot 1.3.0.M5 in another project and never had this problem.

My Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@WebAppConfiguration
public class WiremockTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(options().port(8888).notifier(new ConsoleNotifier(true)));

    @Test
    public void testStub() {
        wireMockRule.stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/test"))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withHeader("Content-type", "application/json").withStatus(200)));
    }

}
```

I've noticed that some test annotations have changed since version 1.3.0.M5 of Spring Boot and I think this could be the problem. Does Anyone had the same problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried using the wiremock-standalone artifact as described in the docs?

Comment: He, Tom, thanks for your response. I didn't try with the standalone's jar in the classpath, but starting the standalone outside the application it worked.
I've found the solution and will post the answer.

Answer (score 15):

From the wiremock [documentation](http://wiremock.org/docs/getting-started/):

> Currently it is recommended that you use the standalone JAR as a
>   dependency with Spring Boot projects. This avoids a conflict over the
>   Jetty version.

Comment: details of "standalone JAR vs standard JAR" can see [here](http://wiremock.org/docs/download-and-installation/)

Comment: Thanks ! https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.tomakehurst/wiremock-standalone
I encountered the problem when adding springdata solr to a project that was using spring boot in another module.

Answer (score 11):

Using `spring-boot-dependencies:1.5.2` and `spring-cloud-dependencies:Dalston.RC1` I had to add the following to get Wiremock to work:

```xml
...
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Dalston.RC1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    ...

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
        <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In case anyone else hits this issue...

EDIT: Alternatively, a much more concise dependency to use would be:

```xml
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
        <artifactId>wiremock-standalone</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Don't need all the jetty and httpclient deps. -->
</dependencies>
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution.

For some reason the jetty dependencies are not been imported by Maven, so I had to declare them. They are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-continuation</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-http</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-io</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-security</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

If Java 1.8 is used, it's ok to omit the version for Jetty dependencies and use Wiremock 2.5.1. But if it's Java 1.7, as mine, I advice to use Wiremock 2.4.1 and his Jetty dependencies version that is **9.2.13.v20150730**.

I don't know if this is the best solution, but worked like a charm for me. Hope this helps!